# Continuity and Compactness

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

From Rudin

> **Theorem**: Suppose $f$ is a continuous mapping of a compact metric space $X$ into  a metric space $Y$. Then $f(X)$ is compact.

The proof is outlined as follows

> Let $\{ V_\alpha\}$ be a cover of $f(X)$. Since $f$ is continuous , $f^{-1}(V_\alpha)$ is open. Since $X$ is compact, there are finitely many indices, say $\alpha_1, \dots,\alpha_n$ such that
>
> $$ X \subset f^{-1}(V_{\alpha_1}) \cup \dots \cup f^{-1}(V_{\alpha_n})$$

Can someone tell me why exactly we are *sure* that ?

> $$ X \subset f^{-1}(V_{1}) \cup \dots \cup f^{-1}(V_{\alpha})$$

in the first place? In other words, how do we know the collection of open set $\{ f^{-1}(V_{\alpha})\}$ is a cover for $X$? Why is it not possible to have?

$$X \supset  f^{-1}(V_{1}) \cup \dots \cup f^{-1}(V_{\alpha})$$

Or another way to put it is, why is it that the preimage of some open set that could possibly be bigger (or possibly being disjoint from the image set) than the image set, must cover our domain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each point $x\in X$, by definition $f(x)\in f[X]$, so there is some $\alpha$ such that $f(x)\in V_\alpha$, and by definition $x\in f^{-1}[V_\alpha]$. Thus, the sets $f^{-1}[V_\alpha]$ cover $X$, and they’re open because $f$ is continuous. Finally, $X$ is compact, so some finite subcollection of them covers $X$.

Comment: *Thus, the sets ....* okay this is the part I am not sure about. WHY? does it follow from the fact that we can take *all* $x \in X$?

Comment: @sidht: Yes. **No matter what** $x\in X$ you pick, $f(x)$ is in $f[X]$ and is therefore contained in one of the sets $V_\alpha$. The definition of $f^{-1}$ then tells you that $x\in f^{-1}[V_\alpha]$. Thus, every point of $X$ is in at least one of the sets $f^{-1}[V\alpha]$.